# Search not working for HTTPS. Works for HTTP (Could not find stored procedure 'proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping'.)

Tags: 2013, search, https

We are facing issue with our SharePoint 2013 Search. 
Search works as expected when accessing site on HTTP. However on searching with HTTPS protocal we get below error.

**There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator.**

Correlation ID: fc87609e-2dac-2087-bc14-21c49abd51da

Looking at the logs found this;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping'.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 at

> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock) 
>   ClientConnectionId:a08ddeb5-1d86-4cf3-a4ad-8fa433e94e6b  Error
>   Number:2812,State:62,Class:16

I searched the net but not able to make out where exactly to look. and how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you apply any updates in you farm?

Comment: Are you using AAMs and are you only crawling the Default zone?

Answer (score 0):

Do you install SP before CU Installation? Be aware that all updates for SP 2013 require SP 2013 SP1 to be installed first.

After that, you need to run psconfig, otherwise, the crawl might no longer work.

[October 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/10/11/october-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)